# Trying to get links from web

Tags: python, xpath, hyperlink, scrapy, href

The code only gets 1 URL listing then stops. It is supposed to get 209 items. Why does it only print one line?

```
def parse_link(self, response):

    # Extract the list of products 
    results = response.xpath('//li[@class="s-item   "]')



    # Extract info for each product
    for product in results:
        name = product.xpath('//*[@class="s-item__link"]').extract_first()[30:124]

    yield{
    "Name":name,
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without any other information. Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: It looks like you are using yield which is a generator statement. are you calling this function through a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect indents (you need to move `yield` inside `for` loop):

```
def parse_link(self, response):

    # Extract the list of products 
    results = response.xpath('//li[@class="s-item   "]')



    # Extract info for each product
    for product in results:
        name = product.xpath('//*[@class="s-item__link"]').extract_first()[30:124]

        yield {"Name":name,}
```